# add data into firebase using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to add data into firebase DB using angularjs but when click the add button nothing happens and function not called and no error appeared in console. Where is the problem in my code?

addPost.html

```
<body ng-controller="AddPostCtrl">

<div class="blog-masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
            <a class="blog-nav-item " href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="addPost.html">Add Post</a>

        </nav>
    </div> </div>

<div class="container">


    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="AddPost()">
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Create Post</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtTitle">Post</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" ng-model="article.title" type="text" placeholder="Post name" class="form-control input-md">

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Textarea -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtPost">Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!--<textarea class="form-control" id="txtPost" name="txtPost"></textarea>-->
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="txtPost" ng-model="article.post" name="txtPost" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!--<input id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add" />-->
                    <input id="singlebutton" ng-disabled="!article.title || !article.post" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add" />

                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>


</div> 

</body>
```

addPost.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.addPost', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/addPost', {
            templateUrl: 'addPost/addPost.html',
            controller: 'AddPostCtrl'
        });
    }]).controller('AddPostCtrl', ['$scope','$firebase',function($scope,$firebase) {
        console.log("This was called.");
        $scope.AddPost = function(){
            var title = $scope.article.title;
            var post = $scope.article.post;
            var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
            var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);
            fb.$push({ title: title,post: post}).then(function(ref) {
                console.log(ref);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error:", error);
            });

        }
    }]);
```

scripts in index.html

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="addPost/addPost.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this an old project? Why are you using such old versions of firebase libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Async Loading... you loaded the firebase after script.js.... Your suppose to load it after like this:

```
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="addPost/addPost.js"></script>
```

So now it actually knows methods and variables provided both by AngularFire and Firebase... Everything you Imported is basically a Js File.. It goes through angular first then Firebase, then Angularfire(Which needs to be imported after Firebase and AngularFire so it recieves variables and methods from them), and then finnaly your scripts which will use all the libaries available.. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok @merna what do you see on your console? Any 404 Erros? If not what errors are you getting? If your not seeing errors in your console then whats the problem?

Comment: nothing ,, i should see "This was called." if the function called ,, i think this mean there is problem in form or my Html but i don't find it !! @Dsafds

Comment: Ok @merna can you debug your code.. Or I will solve it Very quickly if you just demonstrate your problem in a plunker and you give me the url so i can edit: http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: Can you give me your sign in creds so i can login and see problem.. I cant sign up for some reason: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/gitcloning#openfile-README.md

Comment: mernadev@gmail.com ,, 09876543 @Dsafds

Comment: Authentication failed @merna

Comment: @merna this is a very confusing layout you got here... Why not just put all your configs inside app.js? And also ngRoute it self is depreceated... The better version is [UI-Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)...